# Android run-as writing permission on sdcard

Tags: android, adb

I have a not-rooted adroid device.
I want to use adb and the command

```
run-as com.mypackage.app
```

to copy some files from my app to the sdcard.

But when I do

```
cp /data/data/com.mypackage.app /sdcard/
```

I get: Permission denied

I added in the manifest of my app the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And I allowed the permission to access the storage from settings-apps, but it still doesn't work.
What can I do to get write permission?

Comment: /sdcard is NOT 'the sd card'. And not a removable micro sd card.

Comment: You can try to write to a different path like `/data/local/tmp` instead.